# Angular 6 app after refresh redirects to root

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, router

I have problem with my angular 6 app, after refresh it goes back to root. I found where is problem but I don't know how to change or add code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { UserService } from "../../service/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-navbar",
  templateUrl: "./navbar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./navbar.component.css"]
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  uid: string;
  spec: string;
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.statusChange.subscribe(userData => {
      if (userData) {
        this.name = userData.name;
        this.email = userData.email;
        this.uid = userData.uid;
        this.spec = userData.spec;
      } else {
        this.name = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.uid = null;
        this.spec = null;
      }
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(userData => {
      if (userData) {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log("user is login");
        const user = this.userService.getProfile(); 
        if (user && user.name) {
          this.name = user.name;
          this.email = user.email;
          this.uid = user.uid;
          this.spec = user.spec;
        }
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);// **REFRESH PROBLEM**
      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        console.log("user is logout");
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
      }
    });
  }
  onlogout() {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        this.userService.remove();
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      });
  }
}
```

For example if i add in  this.router.navigate(["/"]) some of my routes it will always redirect to that new root, but if i delete all, it will go back to root again. Maybe local storage can help, but i dont know how to implement :(

**Updated**
Routing module

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: "",
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
      { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
      {
        path: "pacijent/:id",
        component: PacijentComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },

      {
        path: "pacijent/:id/edit",
        component: PacijentEditComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: "novi-pacijent",
        component: NoviPacijentComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: "istorija/:id/:id",
        component: NalazComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      { path: "**", component: NotfoundComponent }
    ])
  ],
```

Comment: Can you provide you routing module and also app.module file code here

Comment: Np, added, you can check.

Answer (score 1):

> **`"/"`** will always take you to the root.

Mention right path where you want to land.

Ex :

```
this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"])
```

Comment: But i want to stay on current url after refresh.

Comment: Then try `this.router.navigate(["./"])`

Comment: Again same thing :(

Comment: Can you explain why this is  this.router.navigate(["/"]); needed.@ViktorMolnar

Comment: It will point to the current route. It looks there is wrong implementation in your code. BTW why do you want to refresh ?

Comment: Atm site is in dev mode, i am doing someting on route /example/example/example/:id after ctrl save in visual code i go back to root, than navigate back to see changes...annoying -.- @SunilSingh

Comment: @Sreemat cuz after log in redirecting user to dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be on the current page after refreshing then use `this.router.url`

You can replace `this.router.navigate(["/"]);` to `this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);`

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to stay on current route just place

```
this.router.navigate([""]);
```

Will reload the route but you have to set the reuseroute strategy to false to force reload the route.

If you want to pass any query params along with it

```
let params = ...; // define query params

this.router.navigate([""], params);
```